# 3D передвижение по сетке AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

Интересует, возможно есть фреймворк или либа для удобного передвижение блока по 3D сетке?

Существует такая ситуация:

1. Есть фон (предположим, это земля).
2. Есть куб (предположим, это существо).
3. Данный куб может передвигаться не просто по координатам, а только плавно переходя из одного квадрата в другой (т.е именно по этой сетке, которую до этого еще необходимо расположить на наклонном фоне)
4. Куб должен передвигаться в центр каждого квадрата.
5. Центры блоков между собою имеют расстояние в 50px.
6. Каждый куб имеет размер 50x50.

Возможно как-то это реализовать с помощью фреймворков или либ, либо придется самому что-то изобретать?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А можно подробнее о том, что вы подразумеваете под понятием "3d-сетка"? По описанию очень похоже на [изометрическую проекцию][1]. Если я прав, то итайте [эту][2] статью, раздел "Изометрические движки".


  [1]: http://demiart.ru/forum/uploads5/post-678834-1275023812.png
  [2]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/112347/

Comment: Да, это действительно то, что нужно. И из статьи по совету автора статьи я выбрал as3isolib. Но вот только не понимаю, как же все-таки заставить приведенный мой пример работать на этом. Возможно есть какие-то уроки или простенький пример? (достаточно лишь блока и его перемещения между клетками, дабы понять вообще как это все работает)